# Expo Geofence exit event is always triggered upon startup

Tags: react-native, expo, geofencing

I am developing an app that would send data to my server based on the user entering and exiting a region using Expo Location. Currently testing on an Android emulator.

However, the exit event is triggered for all regions upon the app startup. Is this the expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Geolocation:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await Location.startGeofencingAsync(GEO_LOC, region)

    })();
    return async() =>{
      await Location.stopGeofencingAsync(GEO_LOC)
    }
  }, []);
```

TaskManager :

```
  TaskManager.defineTask(GEO_LOC, ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
    if (error) {
      // check `error.message` for more details.
      return;
    }
    if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
      console.log("You've entered region:", region.identifier);
      socket.emit('court:increment', region.identifier)

    }
    if (eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
      console.log("You've left region:", region.identifier);
      socket.emit('court:decrement', region.identifier)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @xtra No I didn't. I had to come up with a work around of my own.